# How to pass data from activity or fragment to viewmodel?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mvvm, android-mvvm

I am creating a project in which i am using themoviedb api to fetch data. For this I am using MVVM architecture. From MovieListFragment , I want to pass category such as popular, top_rated to MovieViewModel for filtering the movies accordingly , but there i am getting null value.

Here is MovieListFragment class :-

```
public class MovieListFragment extends Fragment {

    private MovieViewModel movieViewModel;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org";
    private static final String API_KEY = "API_KEY";
    private String category;

    private GridView gridView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie_list, container, false);
        gridView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.images_grid_view);

        movieViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MovieViewModel.class);
        movieViewModel.setCategory(category);  // from here i am passing value
        movieViewModel.getMoviesRepository().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<MovieResults>() {  // error line no :- 76
                @Override
                public void onChanged(MovieResults movieResults) {
                    final List<MovieResults.ResultsBean> listOfMovies = movieResults.getResults();  // error line no :- 79

                    MovieListAdapter mAdapter = new MovieListAdapter(getContext(), listOfMovies);
                    gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            mCallback.onImageSelected(position, listOfMovies);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        return rootView;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

Here is MovieViewModel class :-

```
public class MovieViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private String category;
    private static final String API_KEY = "api_key";
    private MovieRepository repository;
    private MutableLiveData<MovieResults> listOfMovies;

    public MovieViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        Log.d("MovieViewModel", category); // but here i am getting null value
        listOfMovies = repository.getListOfMovies(category, API_KEY);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<MovieResults> getMoviesRepository() {
        return listOfMovies;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

I am getting error like this :-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.mountblue.moviesapp.entity.MovieResults.getResults()' on a null object reference
        at com.mountblue.moviesapp.fragment.MovieListFragment$2.onChanged(MovieListFragment.java:79)
        at com.mountblue.moviesapp.fragment.MovieListFragment$2.onChanged(MovieListFragment.java:76)
```

Comment: I don't know why it's not working in your case but your question is the answer to my question. it's working fine in my project. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since the Category is read by the constructor of MovieViewModel before the setter, it is always null.

What about category as method arguments?

```
public class MovieViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private static final String API_KEY = "api_key";
    private MovieRepository repository;
    private MutableLiveData<MovieResults> listOfMovies = new MutableLiveData<MovieResults>();

    public MovieViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<MovieResults> getMoviesRepository(category) {
        loadData(category);
        return listOfMovies;
    }

    private void loadData(category) {
        // Do an asynchronous operation to fetch MovieResults.
        repository.getListOfMovies(category, API_KEY);

        ...
        // Receive asynchronous result in callback

        // Post the result after getting the asynchronous result.
        listOfMovies.postValue(response)
    }
}
```

For a more detailed implementation, need a repository class.

Documents:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `null` value for the string `category` in line `movieViewModel.setCategory(category);`, it means the field `category` of `MovieListFragment` is null.

Try checking if you have invoked the `setCategory(String category)` method on the `fragment`.

If that's not the case, please elaborate on the error. E.g. on which line it occurs etc.

Answer (score 0):

**In MovieListFragment class:**

First delete this line: `movieViewModel.setCategory(category);`

And pass "category" here: `movieViewModel.getMoviesRepository(category)`
like code below:

```
movieViewModel.getMoviesRepository(category).observe(getActivity(), new Observer<MovieResults>() {  // error line no :- 76
            @Override
            public void onChanged(MovieResults movieResults) {
                final List<MovieResults.ResultsBean> listOfMovies = movieResults.getResults();  // error line no :- 79

                MovieListAdapter mAdapter = new MovieListAdapter(getContext(), listOfMovies);
                gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        mCallback.onImageSelected(position, listOfMovies);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

**In MovieViewModel class:**

Move this line inside getMoviesRepository(String category) `listOfMovies = repository.getListOfMovies(category, API_KEY);`

And just remove category variable and `setCategory()` method from `MovieViewModel` class like this:

```
public class MovieViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    
    private static final String API_KEY = "api_key";
    private MovieRepository repository;
    private MutableLiveData<MovieResults> listOfMovies;

    public MovieViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        
    }

    public MutableLiveData<MovieResults> getMoviesRepository(String category) {
        Log.d("MovieViewModel", category); // but here i am getting null value
        listOfMovies = repository.getListOfMovies(category, API_KEY);
        return listOfMovies;
    }

}
```

Comment: How `repository` is created?

Comment: repository class just like a model class, but it gets and sets data to an offline room database using the DAO interface, and can get and set data also from an online server.
I can't find a good and simple java example but see this simple project in GitHub. they use a remote and local repository 
https://github.com/segunfamisa/android-mvvm-sample/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/segunfamisa/sample/mvvm/data/repository

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer! Yes, I understand that it can be a Room database. I meant, how was it created (like `repository = new ...`)? Because we don't pass `repository` inside `MovieViewModel` directly (and I don't see, how it is created). It's not a problem of your code, but the author and all repliers.